# SQLAlchemy / SQLite How to create table and then store data in it with Python / Flask

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Hi I'm trying to create a table in the sqlite db where I should store a user and password.
The table is created correctly (I checked with sqlite command), but when is trying to store the user and pwd it returns an error saying the pwd column table doesn't exist, while I checked and it does!!
I must have missed something in my python code, could you please help?
I think I have done something wrong probably when I create the table(as you can see in the code) I use Metadata() and passed engine to create_all, but when I define the User class I use db.Model and then define the columns with db.Column(db.String), I think maybe is because when I create the table there's no reference to db. ?
I attach a screenshot of the code I have done.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMwhO.jpg

Sqlite verification:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7P6v.png

CODE CLASS USER:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///data-users.sqlite'

engine= create_engine(app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'])
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

#CREATE TABLE
meta=MetaData()
userstable = Table('user', meta, \
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key = True, autoincrement=True), \
    Column('username', String, unique = True), \
    Column('pwd', String))
meta.create_all(engine)

class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key = True, autoincrement=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = True)
    pwd = db.Column(db.String(64)) 

    def __init__(self,id,username,pwd):
        self.id=id
        self.username = username
        self.pwd = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(pwd)
```

Here is how I try to store the user and pwd, it should add a new row in the table

```
        from store_user_db import User, db
        
        DICP_FTP_DESTINATION_PSW=self.submit_pwd()
        db.create_all()
        user = User(id=001,username="ita_itf", pwd=DICP_FTP_DESTINATION_PSW)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
```

ERROR:

```
OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table user has no column named pwd
[SQL: INSERT INTO user (id, username, pwd) VALUES (?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: (1, 'ita_itf', 'xxx')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and start an interactive Python shell, then type the following:

```
from name import db
db.create_all()
```

where `name` is the name of your project.

Comment: Look in my code, I have already done that, maybe something wrong with the session? I have no idea I'm going mad